# Writing a calculation in Dart

Tags: dart, calculation

I am trying to write a calculation feature.

I have a List that looks like that

```dart
List<Map> sections = [
  {
     "alias": "sectionOne",
     "children": [
         {
            "alias": "sectionOne",
            "fields": [
             {
              "name": "fieldOne",
              "value": 10
             },
            {
             "name": "fieldThree",
             "value": 10
             },
             {
               "name": "fieldFour",
              "value": 20
            },
           ]
        }
     ],
     "fields": [
       {
        "name": "fieldOne",
        "value": 10
       },
       {
        "name": "fieldThree",
        "value": 10
       },
       {
        "name": "fieldFour",
        "value": 20
       },
     ]
  },
  {
     "alias": "sectionTwo",
     "fields": [
       {
        "name": "fieldTwo",
        "value": 10
       },
       {
        "name": "fieldSeven",
        "value": 9
       },
     ]
  }
];
```

I have a string that looks like this `=([sectionOne:fieldOne]*[sectionTwo:fieldTwo])*[sectionOne:fieldThree]` please keep in mind this string can have more sections and fields.

I need to get the value of each section and field and then run the calculation keeping BODMAS in mind.

Any suggestions please.

EDIT:

Unfortunately the spec has slightly changed and they want to include keywords such as SUM(), more to come here is an example =([sectionOne:fieldOne]*[sectionTwo:fieldTwo]) * sum([sectionOne:fieldThree]) basically each section has a child list called children, and the same fields exists in the children, I can write the code to sum up them values, am just not sure how to check if the keyword sum' is part of the match.group`, any suggestions please?

Thank you

Comment: Do you need the product of all values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```dart
print(sections
      .map((section) =>
          section['fields'].map((field) => field['value']).toList())
      .toList());
// OUTPUT
// [[10, 10], [10]]
```

Or, from Dart 2.3 :

```dart
print([
    for (var section in sections)
      [for (var field in section['fields']) field['value']]
]);
```

If you need an array containing all values :

```dart
print([
    for (var section in sections)
      for (var field in section['fields']) field['value']
]);
// OUTPUT
// [10, 10, 10]
```

To have the product of elements of an array :

```dart
print([10, 10, 10].reduce((a, b) => a * b));

// OUTPUT
// 1000
```

Comment: The OP mentioned BODMAS, so I think operations than multiplication might come up...

Comment: I know, but it was quite unclear, so I am waiting for its answer to edit my answer if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple problem to solve: it involves parsing a template to create a string expression, and then parsing the string expression to evaluate it numerically.

For the second step, you could use a library (such as [function_tree](https://pub.dev/packages/function_tree) - shameless plug!). For the first step, the easiest would be to use regular expressions to parse your formula, extract map keys and replace brackets with the value read from `sections`, such as:

```dart
final re = RegExp(r'\[([^:]+):([^\]]+)\]');

final expressionWithValues = expression.replaceAllMapped(re, (match) {
  final key1 = match.group(1),
      key2 = match.group(2),
      map = sections.where((map) => map['alias'] == key1).first,
      field = map['fields'].where((field) => field['name'] == key2).first;
  return field['value'].toString();
});
```

This would turn an expression like `([sectionOne:fieldOne]*[sectionTwo:fieldTwo])*[sectionOne:fieldThree]` into an expression like `(10*10)*10`, which can be fed into an appropriate `function_tree` function to be parsed as a mathematical expression.

For example:

```dart
import 'package:function_tree/function_tree.dart';

main() {
  List<Map> sections = [
    {
      "alias": "sectionOne",
      "fields": [
        {"name": "fieldOne", "value": 10},
        {"name": "fieldThree", "value": 10},
        {"name": "fieldFour", "value": 20},
        // added by me...
        {"name": "fieldFive", "value": 2}
      ]
    },
    {
      "alias": "sectionTwo",
      "fields": [
        {"name": "fieldTwo", "value": 10},
        {"name": "fieldSeven", "value": 9},
      ]
    }
  ];

  for (final expression in [
    // OP's example
    '([sectionOne:fieldOne]*[sectionTwo:fieldTwo])*[sectionOne:fieldThree]',
    // More examples
    '[sectionOne:fieldOne]+[sectionTwo:fieldTwo]*[sectionOne:fieldThree]',
    '[sectionTwo:fieldSeven]^[sectionOne:fieldFive]+sin([sectionOne:fieldThree])'
  ]) {
    final re = RegExp(r'\[([^:]+):([^\]]+)\]');

    final expressionWithValues = expression.replaceAllMapped(re, (match) {
      final key1 = match.group(1),
          key2 = match.group(2),
          map = sections.where((map) => map['alias'] == key1).first,
          field = map['fields'].where((field) => field['name'] == key2).first;
      return field['value'].toString();
    });

    print('$expression:');
    print('$expressionWithValues = ${expressionWithValues.interpret()}\n');
  }
}
```

```
([sectionOne:fieldOne]*[sectionTwo:fieldTwo])*[sectionOne:fieldThree]:
(10*10)*10 = 1000

[sectionOne:fieldOne]+[sectionTwo:fieldTwo]*[sectionOne:fieldThree]:
10+10*10 = 110

[sectionTwo:fieldSeven]^[sectionOne:fieldFive]+sin([sectionOne:fieldThree]):
9^2+sin(10) = 80.45597888911063
```

(function_tree, of course, respect BODMAS and gives you access to all the mathematical functions you'd expect, such as sin in the above example.)

Comment: Hi pal, this is absolutely brilliant, thank you so much.

I have one other question, unfortunately the spec has slightly changed and they want to include keywords such as SUM(), more to come

here is an example `=([sectionOne:fieldOne]*[sectionTwo:fieldTwo]) * sum([sectionOne:fieldThree])`

basically each section has a child list called `children`, and the same fields exists in the `children`, I can write the code to `sum` up them values, am just not sure how to check if the keyword `sum' is part of the `match.group`, any suggestions please?